# German Umlaut in html

Tags: php, html, special-characters, meta-tags

I see on stackoverflow many threads with these question, but I can't found any answer for my problem.
I see the german umlauts anytime and allways as "special characters".

This is my implementation:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);

require ("plugins/phpmailer/...");
require ('plugins/phpmailer/...');
require ("include/...");
require ("include/...");
require ("include/...");
?>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="css/...">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/..." 
    type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>ähm...
```

This code doesn't work. I see an special char, but not the ä or what ever...
What is wrong in my code?

Sorry for this question, but I can't find any clever solution.

Comment: have you checked if you *file* is saved as utf-8 on the server, too? and check if your webserver for some reason sends contradicting headers.

Comment: Or if you are getting the data from a database you should do SET NAMES UTF8.

Comment: Thank you Franz! That was the reason! The database format is ok, but the file-format was not ok. Looks as if it were unicode. In UltraEdit 15 I can't recognize this absolte exactly. The menu item text is "unicode/utf8 to utf8". hmmm... Ok, now it is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This works:
ÄËÏ...

What I typed in was (with spaces removed):  & # 196 ; & # 203; & # 207; ...

For more information, google HTML umlaut, or see [this page](http://www.starr.net/is/type/htmlcodes.html) or any of several others google will get you.

Comment: Thank you, but please see the answer from Franz!

Comment: this answer would've been great in ASCII-times. but since UTF was introduced, it's better to make sure it is actually used all the way through.